# SQL Pivot multiple column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, conditional-aggregation

I have table like this:-

[image]

and want output like this:-

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Tag the database you are using ? Do you need the solution in only pivot or alternatives are also fine for you ?

Comment: SQL Server, pivot solution should be nice else alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a more standard/general approach (conditional aggregation) for this problem that would work across multiple Databases (including SQL Server).

```
SELECT
 ID
,MAX(CASE WHEN DOMAIN = 'A' THEN SCORE END) AS DOMAIN_A
,MAX(CASE WHEN DOMAIN = 'A' THEN BAND  END) AS BAND_A
,MAX(CASE WHEN DOMAIN = 'B' THEN SCORE END) AS DOMAIN_B
,MAX(CASE WHEN DOMAIN = 'B' THEN BAND  END) AS BAND_B
,MAX(CASE WHEN DOMAIN = 'C' THEN SCORE END) AS DOMAIN_C
,MAX(CASE WHEN DOMAIN = 'C' THEN BAND  END) AS BAND_C
,MAX(CASE WHEN DOMAIN = 'D' THEN SCORE END) AS DOMAIN_D
,MAX(CASE WHEN DOMAIN = 'D' THEN BAND  END) AS BAND_D
,MAX(CASE WHEN DOMAIN = 'E' THEN SCORE END) AS DOMAIN_E
,MAX(CASE WHEN DOMAIN = 'E' THEN BAND  END) AS BAND_E
FROM MyTable
Group by ID
;
```

Note : If you are not using T-SQL (SQL Server), Pivot function won't work as it is specific to SQL Server

Comment: @Raunak - Did the above solution work for you? Do share thoughts/comments.